# VideoView/MediaPlayer error causing video playback failure some of the time

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-videoview, galaxy-tab

I'm working on a tablet app which lets you view videos and page through them using a ViewPager. The videos are using a VideoView. It's working just fine on a Xoom and Transformer Prime. On the Galaxy Tab 10.1 more often than not the video errors after a new page has been selected. 
I'm getting:

```
MediaPlayer Error(1,-214783648) 
VideoView Error: 1, -214783648
```

Videos are loaded as pages are selected and i'm using an onPrepared listener to start playing the video as soon as it's loaded. The error seems to throw before onPrepared is called, but I can see the first frame of video, so it appears to have loaded. 
I've tried delaying playback but that didn't improve anything. I've tried loading the video again from OnErrorListener once it's failed which seems to work some of the time. The Galaxy Tab is the only tablet stuck on 3.1, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the Galaxy Tab 10.1 (or Android 3.1... remains to be seen) can only decode two videos at a time. Since I'm using a viewPager there are potentially 3 videos loaded at any given time. The solution (though a crappy one) is to only ever have two videos loaded by delaying load until a page has been selected and making sure that other views (except for the last active view) have been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a few days ago. You don't need to destroy your `Views` my dear anakin78z.

I solved the same problem on my tablet by adding my own `SimpleOnPageChangeListener` on my `ViewPager` and by adding the following code into my listener :

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    stopVideoView(position - 1);
    stopVideoView(position + 1);
    startVideoView(position);
}

private void startVideoView(int index) {
    VideoView videoView = getVideoView(index);
    if (videoView != null)
        videoView.start();
}

private void stopVideoView(int index) {
    VideoView videoView = getVideoView(index);
    if (videoView != null) {
        videoView.stopPlayback();
}

private VideoView getVideoView(int index){
    // Retrieve your videoviews here
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this response come a bit too late but I hope it would help someone!